# Questions on learning assembly for a CTF challenge

Tags: assembly, x86

I've just started to dip into Assembly for CTF reversing challenges, and am having a great time. The current challenge I'm working on has me stumped, however - hoping someone can help with a few basic Assembly questions - or point me to good resources.

I ran the binary provided for the challenge through Binary Ninja and identified the key function - tracing the logic within that function is giving me problems.

The function starts in a fairly straightforward way - I've added my own comments to the best of my understanding:

```
08048661  push    ebp {__saved_ebp}  ;Push old base pointer onto stack
08048662  mov     ebp, esp {__saved_ebp} ;Function preamble (?) 
08048664  sub     esp, 0x18
08048667  sub     esp, 0xc
0804866a  push    dword [ebp+0x8 {arg1}] {var_2c} ;var_2c is user input (arg1)
0804866d  call    strlen ;Get the string length of user input
08048672  add     esp, 0x10 ;?? 
08048675  mov     dword [ebp-0x10 {var_14}], eax  ;Assign EAX to var_14
08048678  cmp     dword [ebp-0x10 {var_14}], 0x13 
;Compares string length to 0x13 (decimal 19) - if it's longer continue
0804867c  ja      0x8048688
```

This first block seems to get the string length of the user input - and if the string length is greater than 19 it continues to the next block.

This next block is where I think my understanding is incorrect:

```
08048688  mov     eax, dword [ebp+0x8 {arg1}]     
;Set EAX to the memory location of the user input (arg1) 
0804868b  movzx   eax, byte [eax]         
;Replace EAX with the first byte of EAX (arg1)
0804868e  cmp     al, 0x61            
;Compare the first byte of EAX with 0x61 (decimal 97 / binary 01100001)
;if equal, continue to next block
08048690  je      0x8048699
```

This would imply that the first byte of the correct response would have to be 01100001 - but that seems to be contradicted by the next block:

```
08048699  mov     eax, dword [ebp+0x8 {arg1}] 
;Set EAX to the memory location of the user input (arg1)
0804869c  add     eax, 0x1 
;Add 0x1 to EAX (decimal 1 / binary 00000001)
0804869f  movzx   eax, byte [eax]
;Replace EAX with only the first byte of EAX (arg1+1)
080486a2  cmp     al, 0x71           
;Compare the first byte of EAX with 0x71 (decimal 113 / binary 01110001)
;if equal, continue to next block
080486a4  je      0x80486ad
```

This is where I'm currently stuck - if the first byte of the input needs to be decimal 97 / binary 01100001 to pass the second block, then how could adding 1 to it possibly result in the decimal 113 / binary 01110001 required to pass the third block of code?

I'm not sure where my understanding of the code is incorrect - very much appreciate any tips or pointers. Apologize if this covers basic knowledge - I'm working through these on my own.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it's not adding one that should result in `113`. If you look closer you should notice that adding `1` to `eax` is done before reading the character value again to `eax`. Only this new loaded value is compared with `0x71`. So this first operation just serves as an index incrementation.

A bit more explanation:

```
08048699  mov     eax, dword [ebp+0x8 {arg1}]
```

This loads the address of the input buffer to `eax`.

```
0804869c  add     eax, 0x1
```

After this `eax` points to the second character in the input buffer.

```
0804869f  movzx   eax, byte [eax]
```

This line loads the character that `eax` points to (input buffer), to `eax` (extending with zeros to 32bits).

And only after the last line you have your comparison with `0x71`. So the second character should be 'q'.

> If add eax, 0x1 points eax to the second character in the input buffer, does that mean that movzx eax, byte [eax] without add eax, 0x1 points to the first character in the buffer?

Yes, and you had that code/pattern in the first block under addresses: `08048688` & `0804868b`. There's no `add eax,1` and the rest is the same.

> does `dword [ebp+0x8 {arg1}]` always signify the input buffer, or only in this case?

Only in this case - this `[ebp+0x8]` basically points to the argument on the stack - in this case it's input buffer but it doesn't have to be like that.

BTW, I think you would be better with such questions on [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you - this was incredibly helpful.

Comment: May I ask a followup question? If `add     eax, 0x1` points eax to the second character in the input buffer, does that mean that `movzx   eax, byte [eax]` _without_ `add     eax, 0x1` points to the _first_ character in the buffer? Also, does `dword [ebp+0x8 {arg1}]` always signify the input buffer, or only in this case? Finally, thank you for pointing me to Reverse Engineering - I was unsure if that community only covered actual reverse engineering and not also exercises and CTF challenges.

Comment: see my updated answer; if you find this useful please vote-up and if it answers your question please mark it as such.

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you!